# How to store and query events in redis by date, user and specific fields?

Tags: redis

I want to create a system that can store events, get them by some of event fields.

Here is the schema:

```
public class Event
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime From {get; set;}
    public DateTime To {get;set;}
    public bool IsAllDay
    // any other properties
}
```

How can I organize Redis in order to be able to store these events and query them by **UserId**, **From-To** (date range) and **IsAllDay** fields?
I also want to query by multiple parameters at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look into [Redisearch](https://oss.redis.com/redisearch/)
This will let you run queries on fields within a Redis hash